# mobile not being recognized by Ubuntu13.04

Tags: ubuntu, mobile

I connected my China mobile to laptop via cable. On the phone I selected the option `mass storage`. Then it messages on the phone as "done". But as I was expecting I would be able to see the contents of the mobile (memory card, inbuilt disk) it didn't happen so.

I checked `df -h` but it doesn't show my phone. When I click on the "file" menu of the Ubuntu launcher to see the devices of my computer, it doesn't show up.

The same way when I was earlier connecting on my Windows 7, it used to reflect perfectly. But what may be the issue with my Ubuntu13.04?

@terdon please find below the output

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ dmesg | tail -n 40
[  687.926249] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[  687.926252] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[  687.926256] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[  687.926272] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 495615
[  687.926279] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[  687.926283] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[  696.056096] usb 7-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1694.288050] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[ 1694.471086] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=0002
[ 1694.471093] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 1694.471096] usb 7-1: Product: MT6225 
[ 1694.471099] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc
[ 1694.471101] usb 7-1: SerialNumber: 533807205600090
[ 1694.476542] scsi6 : usb-storage 7-1:1.0
[ 1695.480108] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK      6225 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1695.483121] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK      6225 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1695.487030] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1695.487241] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1695.497177] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3964928 512-byte logical blocks: (2.03 GB/1.89 GiB)
[ 1695.502101] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1695.502108] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1695.505093] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] 1000 512-byte logical blocks: (512 kB/500 KiB)
[ 1695.508140] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1695.508145] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1695.511104] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 1695.511111] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1695.516140] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1695.516146] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1695.538535] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1695.538542] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1695.548183]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1695.551261] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1695.551270] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1695.560464]  sdc: sdc1
[ 1695.586091] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1695.586099] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1695.586103] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1695.592133] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1695.592141] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1695.592146] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

> EDIT

@slm, I created the 2 device files `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` as shown below. But a surprise! Without connecting my mobile to laptop, I created the files and I confirmed it by running `ls`. But after connecting my mobile, those files disappeared!!! Why so and now how to proceed?

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo mknod /dev/sdb b 8 0
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ cd /dev
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ls sd*
sda  sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sda6  sda7  sda8  sdb
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ sudo mknod /dev/sdc b 8 0
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ !-2
ls sd*
sda  sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sda6  sda7  sda8  sdb  sdc
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ll $_
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 8, 0 Nov  1 20:33 sdc
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ll sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Nov  1 20:09 sda
(the below is after connecting mobile)    
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ls sd*
sda  sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sda6  sda7  sda8
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ls sdb
ls: cannot access sdb: No such file or directory
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ls sdc
ls: cannot access sdc: No such file or directory
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$
```

> EDIT

@slm Now the device files `sdb` and `sdc` are visible. What I did now is that I created the files after connecting the device. But still unable to locate my mobile devices. You can see from the below codes that I wasn't able to mount the file sdb. But you know one thing, when I ran cat /dev/sdb it did output in non-readable format which I did quit by ctrl-c. Does that mean it was reading my mobile disk!

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: /dev/sdb already mounted or /mnt busy
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       9.9G  5.8G  3.6G  62% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            489M  4.0K  489M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  920K   99M   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            497M  672K  496M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5       284M  129M  141M  48% /boot
/dev/sda8       9.5G  7.6G  1.5G  85% /home
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ sudo umount /mnt
umount: /mnt: not mounted
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ ls sd*
sda  sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sda6  sda7  sda8  sdb  sdc
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ sudo umount /dev/sdb
umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/dev$ cd /
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: /dev/sdb already mounted or /mnt busy
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/$
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dmseg | tail -n 40` or so just after connecting the mobile.

Comment: @slm Yes it is USB

Comment: @terdon I would like to add that I got the cell phone repaired recently because it fell and wasn't starting. After that I haven't checked in Windows also. I would check if after the repair it works in Windows or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are 2 storage devices on this device:

```
[ 1695.497177] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3964928 512-byte logical blocks: (2.03 GB/1.89 GiB)
[ 1695.505093] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] 1000 512-byte logical blocks: (512 kB/500 KiB)
```

Did you try mounting the device `/dev/sdb`?

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right to say that there are 2 devices of the sizes as visible in your post (2 GB and 500 KB). Oh! this output shows the 2 devices with name `sdb` and `sdc`. But the problem is that these names aren't present under `/dev`. The output of `ls sd*` is `sda  sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sda6  sda7  sda8`. That's all. So when I run the above `mount` command, it messages "special device /dev/sdb doesn't exist". Oh! I wasn't aware of this command "dmesg" which seems to be very useful. I will learn it.

Comment: `dmesg` shows error/info messages from the kernel.

Comment: @Ravi - so you do not have `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdb1`? You could try creating them. `mknod /dev/sdb 8 0`.

Comment: I did but couldn't succeed. Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: I have added more details on my Q. I am able to create the device files but not able to view my mobile contents

Comment: @Ravi - make a new directory to mount. I suggested `/mnt` but it looks like something else is mounted under there. Make something like `mkdir /mnt2` and then `mount /dev/sdb /mnt2`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11320/discussion-between-ravi-and-slm)

Comment: In this thread I mentioned of the issue with my china mobile. But I should have mentioned that I don't have any problem with my Nokia N73.
Via bluetooth,my laptop is detecting both Nokia N73 and china mobile. But via bluetooth,I can't transfer any data from laptop to china mobile or can't even browse the mobile's files. I am getting some error message. There is no problem accessing/browsing my Nokia N73, also I can transfer data between the laptop and N73 perfectly.
So, can the problem be due to the china mobile!!! Is any setting reqd. in the mobile?